# How to deploy the program from the system tray with shortcut on desktop

Tags: java, awt, system-tray

I have a program which can minimized to tray using AWT, how do I make it so that when a user opens it via a shortcut on the desktop it unfolded, and did not run a new program.

Answer (score 0):

Check [java.awt.SystemTray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) and [How to Use the System Tray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html). But the latter describes on Swing.

Comment: This is not the answer. There's nothing about my question.